# Using neovim, clangd and coc.nvim, why am I getting format: "hello, world" beside printf, and how do I turn this off?

Tags: c, neovim

[Image of the code and the format: "hello, world" beside printf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWrTG.png)

Does anyone know how to disable this?

Comment: This feature is called *inlay hints*. As suggested in [the readme of `coc-clangd` plugin](https://github.com/clangd/coc-clangd), setting `clangd.inlayHints.enable` to `false` in your config file turns the feature off.

Comment: Thanks for informing me. How would I go about disabling this, when I go to the coc-settings.json file, it is empty.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. That's also a great suggestion. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

put

```
  "inlayHint.enable": false,
```

in your coc configuration file or use `:CocCommand document.toggleInlayHint`

You can read more about the feature (which used to be in coc-clangd but has now been moved to coc.nvim) by reading the help pages in neovim, assuming the coc is installed: `:help coc-inlayHint`